# How to specify indirect gem dependency version in rails Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemfile

In my **Gemfile**, i have:

```
 gem 'msgpack_rails'
 gem 'google-authenticator-rails'
 .. etc
```

Inside **Gemfile.lock** i see:

```
google-authenticator-rails (2.0.0)
      actionpack
      activerecord
      google-qr
      rails
      rotp (= 3.3.0)
```

How can I specify  **actionpack** and **activerecord** versions inside google-authenticator-rails gem ?.

Do I need to write directly inside **Gemfile.lock** like this:

```
google-authenticator-rails (2.0.0)
  actionpack (>2)
  activerecord (>6)
  google-qr
  rails
  rotp (= 3.3.0)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "fix"? Are you saying that `google-authenticator-rails` needs to be more specific about which version of rails it depends on? Or is there an error message you're trying to resolve?

Comment: *"Do I need to write direclty inside Gemfile.lock"* --- **NO.** But I'm not sure what the right answer is at this point, because I'm not 100% sure what your question is.

Comment: What do you mean by "fix"?, I need to specify version.

Comment: "Do I need to write direclty inside Gemfile.lock" --- NO. 
How can i specify the version of indirect gem ?.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I still don't really understand what you are hoping to achieve; this reads like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. If you need a specific version of `actionpack` in a project, then you should state that in the `Gemfile`. Doing this will have no affect on that specific line of the `Gemfile.lock`, but it doesn't need to.

Comment: Are you saying that the wrong version is installed? Or that bundler is failing to resolve your dependencies? Or are you developing the `google-authenticator-rails` gem itself, and are concerned that it's **possible** to install `google-authenticator-rails` with an incompatible version of `actionpack`/`activerecord`?

Comment: Or, are you simply trying to make sense of how `Gemfile`/`Gemfile.lock`s work, and think it would look "nicer" if the version was specified on that line?

Comment: "if the version was specified on that line". yes this is what i want to do. The goal is not to have à nicer look, but it is for security goal.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your original question directly, the correct way to update that part of the `Gemfile.lock` would be to tighten the version constraints here: https://github.com/jaredonline/google-authenticator/blob/a5d3d344cf8f10abd4c0bf85606c632dce48ca80/google-authenticator.gemspec#L27-L32

However, I don't see any evidence why this is necessary. I think you are confused between *dependencies* and *constraints*.

Your project is *already using* activerecord version `6.0.3.2`. Tightening the constraints of `google-authenticator-rails` won't change this fact.

You can see what versions of all dependencies your project is using by running: `bundle list`.